# Cryptography in Python

Tags: python

While `encoding` try to use this line :

```
#Add the header to the file data
    headerdata = struct.pack("4s"+\
                             "I"+\
    str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+"s",header.magicnum, header.size, header.fformat)
    filebytes = headerdata + data
```

But having an error:

> str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+"s",header.magicnum, header.size, header.fformat)
>   struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object

When I'm trying to change it , like: (adding `b`)

```
  str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+b's',header.magicnum, header.size,    header.fformat)
```

it says:

> str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+b's',header.magicnum, header.size, header.fformat)
>   TypeError: must be str, not bytes

how can I solve this proble, using python 3?Thanks for helping

Comment: Just like it says - either `header.magicnum` or `header.fformat` (the two parameters packed with format 's') is something other than a byte string.

Comment: @jasonharper don't know, lost a little bit, trying to figure it out

Comment: @X21: It's not an issue with the encoding of the format string `"4sI~s"`, but an issue with the encoding of the data (either `magicnum` or `fformat`). Both of those need to be `bytes` instances, but currently at least one of them is something else. I'd look closely at `magicnum`, since it's name suggests it might be an actual number.